# iPhone UITableView row drag-move

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drag

How would you know if a row from UITableView has been move via drag?  Is there an event to catch?

Comment: If you are trying to implement re-ordering of rows, then see the docs on it: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html.  You should also go back to all your questions and accept answers on them.

Answer (score 0):

`-(void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`